# Is $\nabla_j\nabla^iu^j=(\operatorname{grad}\operatorname{div}u)^i$ in flat space?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, index-notation

When dealing with the Navier-Stokes equations, one typically models fluids in which the viscous stress depends linearly on the symmetric velocity gradient,
$$\tau^{ij}=2\mu(\nabla u)^{(ij)}=\mu\left(\nabla ^iu^j+\nabla^ju^i\right)$$
So when taking the divergence of the stress, as you do when writing the general continuum equations, we get
$$\nabla_j\tau^{ij}=\mu\nabla_j\nabla^iu^j+\mu\nabla_j\nabla^j u^i$$
The second term can be recognized as just the vector Laplacian of $\boldsymbol u$. However, the first term,
$$\nabla_j\nabla^i u^j$$
Is not so simple. The covariant derivatives $\nabla_j,\nabla^i$ do not necessarily commute. However, if we are working in rectangular coordinates, they do, and one can write
$$\nabla_j\nabla^i u^j=\nabla^i\nabla_ju^j=\nabla^i(\operatorname{div}u)=(\operatorname{grad}\operatorname{div}u)^i$$
And hence
$$\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol\tau=\mu\big(\nabla(\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol u)+\nabla^2\boldsymbol u\big)$$

So, my question is this: Can we always say $\nabla_j\nabla^i u^j=(\operatorname{grad}\operatorname{div}u)^i$ ? I should hope the answer is yes, because, when dealing with incompressible flows, one uses this identity to discard the $\nabla_j\nabla^i u^j$ term from the divergence of the viscous stress. So, my thinking is, if this term is always zero in Cartesian coordinates, it should also be zero in any other coordinate system. But, this is not clear from the expression.

Comment: The commutativity of covariant derivatives depends on the curvature of space, it's not about the coordinate system.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Can you explain what you mean? The expression
$$[\nabla_i,\nabla_j]w_k=w_lR^l{}_{kij}$$
Is true in any coordinate system, but even in flat space, the Riemann tensor is not necessarily zero.

Comment: Actually, sorry, yes it is. Thank you Jackozee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very silly question. Because $\mathbb R^3$ is flat, we can find a coordinate system (e.g, Cartesian) in which the Riemann tensor is zero everywhere. And, due to the following property of the Riemann tensor,
$$[\nabla_c,\nabla_d]w_b=w_aR^a{}_{bcd}$$
In the Cartesian coordinate system we get $[\nabla_b,\nabla_c]=0$ as expected. However, when we change from our original coordinate system $\{x^i\}$ to a new coordinate system $\{\bar x^i\}$ the Riemann tensor transforms as
$$\overline{R}^a{}_{bcd}=\frac{\partial\bar{x}^a}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial \bar{x}^b}\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial \bar{x}^c}\frac{\partial x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^d}R^i{}_{jkl}$$
The components transform linearly. So if the Riemann tensor is zero in one coordinate system, it has to be zero in any other coordinate system for $\mathbb R^3$ and so we can always commute the covariant derivatives.

Comment: Damn no need to throw shade on yourself xD. Maybe you may find this stuff easier to do if you learn the Penrose Diagrammatic notation. It helps you not get lost in the indices. It is discussed in the appendix of a book named "Two spinor calculus" and also certain pages of Road to Reality. I can find the pages if you want.

Comment: @Aplateofmomos I don't think there is anything in this post that could be easier in Penrose's diagramatic notation. That notation is made to perform coordinate-independent calculations, and the only coordinate independent fact here is $R^a{}_{bcd}=0$.